# Extracting a specific data part of a Field Collection Item

Tags: 7, entities

I've been playing around with this for the better part of a few days now with no luck. Here is my Collection data:

Collection name: `field_video_collection`

Within the collection there is a field called: `field_video_file_col`

My fields print fine in my custom `field-collection-item--field_video_collection.tpl.php` template, I followed the documentation according to [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1157794#comment-6270780) to get my template name and I simply print the fields as `<?php print render($content['field_video_file_col']); ?>` etc... within that template.

Now for the fun part, I'd like to extract the `fid` for each `field_video_file_col` item in the collection in any given node and render it as a printed variable. I followed [the answer in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53417/697) here on Stack but it does not seem to work for me. if I do:

```
print '<pre>';
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
print '</pre>';
```

I see I have this as part of the data available to me for `field_video_file_col`

```
["field_video_file_col"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["und"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              array(12) {
                ["fid"]=>
                string(3) "888"
```

So it looks to me that the FID is 888 in this case and I want to render that in my template. My node preprocess function is as such:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {

    $entity_type = 'field_collection_item';
    $bundle_name = 'field_field_video_collection'; // Field name the collection is attached to
    $field_name = 'field_video_file_col'; // Field name within the field collection
    $video_file_fid = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
    if ($video_file_fid) {
      $my_fid = $video_file_fid['fid'];
    }
}
```

***The end result needed*** is that I need to render the variable in my *field-collection-item--field_video_collection.tpl.php* template as:

```
<?php print $video_file_fid; ?>
```

... but this does not seem to work.  I've searched all over and tried many different incarnations of this code and combinations but still no joy.

Comment: You changed MYTHEME to your theme name right? :)

Comment: @Lance - yes I changed it.

Answer (score 8):

I use [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) when work with Field Collection Items. See: [Programmatically create and update field collection with Entity API](http://drupal.org/node/1842304.)

To work with field collections can do smth like this:

```
// Wrap node with Entity API
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
// Get the first item from the muli-value field collection
$raw_collection = $node_wrapper->field_video_collection[0]->value();
// Wrap it with Entity API
$collection = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $raw_collection);
//dsm the old value
debug($collection->field_video_file_col->value());
```

If you already know your field_collection id you can just do:

```
$collection = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $fid);
//dsm the old value
debug($collection->field_video_file_col->value());
```

**UPDATE:**

use the code above in `MYTHEME_preprocess_node`

**UPDATE 2:**

So in your case it will be:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (empty($vars['nid'])) {
    return;
  }
  // Wrap node with Entity API
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $vars['nid']);
  // Get the first item from the muli-value field collection
  $raw_collection = $node_wrapper->field_video_collection[0]->value();
  // Wrap field collection with Entity API
  $collection = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $raw_collection);
  // print value
  $fid = $collection->field_video_file_col->value();
  debug($fid);
}
```

Also you can find answer at [Understanding Field Collection Values](http://drupal.org/node/1477202)

Comment: I follow your code above somewhat but I don't see how this creates and renders a variable in my custom field collection template so I am not sure if this answer has any practical use for me.

Comment: you would stick his code into your `MYTHEME_preprocess_node` function and put your variable in a `$variables` value which your sample code doesnt do.


He's showing you how to get a reference to the `field_collection` entity itself from its node, and then how to nab the field in question from the collection. You take your preprocess function, and inject his code into it.

So you can write the following variable to have in your preprocess function.

 `$vars['video_file_fid'] = $collection->field_video_file_col->value();`

Comment: @tenken thanks. Danny follow the tenken's comment. Just use entity_metadata_wrapper in MYTHEME_preprocess_node

Comment: I read the posts you linked too before I posted this question actually and could not really make heads or tales of it. Using code from above, I am getting WSODs.I am also seeing a message that the variable `node_wrapper` is not used anywhere.

Comment: See example in my UPDATE 2. But please check field names("field_video_collection" and "field_video_file_col") P.S. You are right, there should have been $node_wrapper instead of $node.

Comment: I still don't get this, where is a variable being created for `fid`, the *"file ID"* of the field called `field_video_file_col`? If you look at my original question and code, you can see that I've done a `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` and it reveals that there is an array element of the field called `fid`. I need to create a variable with that in the preprocess function and then print it in my custom field collection template which is already working fine printing the actual fields. So this answer is still too abstract for me and I don't see `fid` in your answer.

Comment: You just should get the idea how to work with field collections. There is no matter how the variables called. `$collection->field_video_file_col->value()` it's your `$fid`. If you didn't get let's talk via email and that publish answer here.

Answer (score -1):

The code from [dropbucket](http://dropbucket.org/node/121) might be helpful to get and prepare all the field collection's data into an array:

```
$fieldname = 'field_lorem_slides';

// Get the items
$slides = array();
foreach($vars[$fieldname] as $delta => $item_id){
    $data = field_collection_item_load($item_id['value']);
    if ($data)){
                $l = isset($data->language) ? $data->language : LANGUAGE_NONE;
        $slides[$delta] = array();

                // Get the field collection's data prepared in an array
                // Alternatively, you could do $slides[$delta] = $data; in order to get the full objects in the array 
        $slides[$delta]['lorem_image'] = '<img src="'.file_create_url($data->field_image[$l][0]['uri']).'">';
        $slides[$delta]['lorem_data'] = isset($data->field_heading[$l]) ? $data->field_heading[$l][0]['safe_value'] : null;
    }
}

// Send the information to the template file
// $vars['slides'] = $slides;
```

Comment: Is this a template preprocess function? If so is it a preprocess page or node function? I'm not seeing any context so I think simply linking to a code snippet without explanation is not too useful.

Comment: Yes it's meant for use in preprocess functions. By the way, when the team I work with was struggling with field collections the most productive approach was found to be installing the devel module and using dsm() to explore the variables in templates and preprocess functions. Field collections are a pig to theme, partly because (erroneously in my view) their field preprocess function gets called both for the field collection field and individual items within it.

Comment: So is it a `_preprocess_node`, `_preprocess_page` function or other?

Comment: That would be a preprocess_node.

Comment: I tired this many different ways but could not get it work within the context of what I am doing, it just does not seem to be apples to apples.

Comment: The answers you need are in milkovsky's post.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this one. The first line gets the object, the second line the fid from it.

```
$field_video_col=current(current($vars["field_video_file_col"]));
$video_file_fid=$field_video_col['fid'];
```

Comment: `current` takes the argument by reference, so you need to put those in separate variables.

Comment: This did not work. I'm getting a message: `Unused local variable 'video_file_fid'. The value of the variable is not used anywhere.A variable is considered unused in the following cases: 
* The value of the variable is not used anywhere or is overwritten immediately.
* The reference stored in the variable is not used anywhere or is overwritten immediately`

Comment: Let's refactor like this then

$tmp=current($vars["field_video_file_col"]);
$field_video_col=current($tmp);
$video_file_fid=$field_video_col['fid];
echo ($video_file_fid);

Comment: The new code above did not work either. There's also a syntax error `['fid]` should be `['fid']` but that's beside the point.