# Field collection with condition node tpl

Tags: theming, entities

I've been researching this for the last few days and I cant find a clear explanation of this issue im facing.  I'm receiving an error when a node has an empty collection with no values.

The collection field: field_window_shade
The fields within the collection: field_question, field_answer

Here is my code that is only looping thru the collection array *within my node.tpl*:

```
            $wrapper  = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
            $formtype = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_window_shade');

            foreach($formtype as $itemid) { 
                 $item = field_collection_field_get_entity($itemid);
                 print $item->field_question['und'][0]['value'];
                 print $item->field_answer['und'][0]['value'];
            }
```

I am after something like this:

```
            $wrapper  = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
            $formtype = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_window_shade');

            if (isset($wrapper->field_question)) {
              foreach($formtype as $itemid) { 
                 $item = field_collection_field_get_entity($itemid);
                 print $item->field_question['und'][0]['value'];
                 print $item->field_answer['und'][0]['value'];
              }
            }
```

I've seen this question asked about 5 different times with 10 different solutions and I can't seem to reach a solution here.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `field_collection_item` in `entity_metadata_wrapper`? I mean this

```
$wrapper  = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$raw_collection = $wrapper->field_window_shade->value();
$fwrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $raw_collection);
```

Now use `$fwrapper` to extract the items (This code is not completely accurate a few modification may be needed)

Visit [Extracting a specific data part of a Field Collection Item](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68407/extracting-a-specific-data-part-of-a-field-collection-item) for more details. Also [Programmatically create and update field collection with Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1842304.) and [Understanding Field Collection Values](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477202) can be helpful.

Comment: You welcome. But your answer which is marked as accepted is not similar to my solution

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using the correct field format (filter) type.

here: $item->field_answer->value->raw();  error is now gone

```
     <?php
            $wrapper         = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
            $raw_collection = $wrapper->field_window_shade->value();

            foreach ($wrapper->field_window_shade as $item): 
                print "<div class='faq collection-item'><h3 class='toggle'><p>" . $item->field_question->value() . "</p></h3>";
                print "<div class='faq-content'><div class='faq-content-inner'><p>" . $item->field_answer->value->raw() . "</p></div></div></div>";
            endforeach; 
        ?>
```